# Unexpected result from parentsUntil

Tags: jquery

So I'm trying to figure out why something I think *should* work isn't, based on [jQuery's API](https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/).

Brief problem overview:

> I have a list of groups and users. Groups can potentially overlap the
>   list of users, and because of this I want to synchronize the
>   checkboxes for each user in any number of groups they might occur in.

Relevant HTML that I'm traversing:

```
<div class="dest" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <ul class="list-unstyled" data-role="role1">
        <li data-id="2">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input name="role1" type="checkbox" value="1;2" checked="checked"> GroupName
                </label>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input name="role1Inclusions" type="checkbox" value="3;2;1" checked="checked">Person1
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input name="role1Inclusions" type="checkbox" value="3;2;2" checked="checked">Person2
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input name="role1Inclusions" type="checkbox" value="3;2;3" checked="checked"> Person3
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input name="role1" type="checkbox" value="2;4" checked="checked"> Person4
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input name="role1" type="checkbox" value="2;1" checked="checked"> Person1
                </label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Explanation of how checkbox values are structured:

> The first number identifies what I'm looking at, `1 = Group, 2 =
>   Person, 3 = PersonInclusion`. For Groups and Persons, the second
>   number is the GroupId/PersonId respectively. For PersonInclusions it's
>   the respective GroupId, and the third number is the PersonId.

Non-working JavaScript ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dt0pkk10/1/)):

```
$('.dest').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"][value^="2;"], input[type="checkbox"][value^="3;"]', function () {
    $('ul[data-role="' + $(this).parentsUntil('.dest').data('role') + '"] input[type="checkbox"][value$=";' + $(this).val().split(";").slice(-1)[0] + '"]:not([value^="1"])').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Working JavaScript ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rx7r7qnq/1/)):

```
$('.dest').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"][value^="2;"], input[type="checkbox"][value^="3;"]', function () {
    $('ul[data-role="' + $(this).closest('.dest').children('ul').data('role') + '"] input[type="checkbox"][value$=";' + $(this).val().split(";").slice(-1)[0] + '"]:not([value^="1;"])').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

If you inspect `$(this).parentsUntil('.dest').data('role')` inside the function you'll see that its type is `undefined`. I find this odd though because it's pretty easy to manually verify that `data-role` is defined on the *only* child element of `.dest`.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This use of value to house compound fields is confusing.  If your able to change this, extracting them into their own data elements (ex data-group="2" data-person="1" ) could possibly make some logic easier and more readable for programmers who come along after you.

Comment: It'd probably make the intentions more clear in the generated html markup, but I'm using C# and I'm referencing an enumeration anyhow. The enumeration has to be sent back to the server with the form along with the associated ids so that I can process it, so *at a minimum* I have to have them in value afaik.I should probably duplicate it anyhow, but it provides no additional benefit, and honestly I find it pretty readable now.

Comment: To you, and right now.  To another programmer, or you 6 months from now? Good luck with that, :)

Comment: You seriously underestimate the clarity benefits of enumerations if you think this isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I missed that the API returns ancestor**s** of the element. I only wanted it where data-role was defined. Fixed the non-working javascript as below:

```
$('.dest').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"][value^="2;"], input[type="checkbox"][value^="3;"]', function () {
    $('ul[data-role="' + $(this).parentsUntil('.dest', '[data-role]').data('role') + '"] input[type="checkbox"][value$=";' + $(this).val().split(";").slice(-1)[0] + '"]:not([value^="1"])').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dt0pkk10/2/)

Answer (score 0):

`.parentsUntil()` returns a collection of elements. The first element in the collection is the parent of the element the method was called on. The last element is a child of the one that matched the stopping rule.

`data(key)` retrieves data from the first element in the collection. What you want is the last one. So add a `.eq(-1)` after the `.parentsUntil()`

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out. I don't want the `.eq(-1)` though, I want to add the optional filter that it provides. Thanks though!